# How can I create a function of a specified class?

Tags: r

In the `kernlab` package in `R`, there is a function `ksvm`, one of whose parameters is `kernel`. The description says that the `parameter can be set to any function, of class kernel`.

I realize that there are various kernels defined in the package, but I am wondering how I might implement my own.

I know how to create functions in `R`, but I am not sure how to give classes to functions.

How might I go about creating a "function of class kernel?"

Comment: Take a look at `? class`.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign its class in the usual way:

```
> foo=function(x){x*2}
> class(foo)
[1] "function"
> class(foo)=c("function","kernel")
> class(foo)
[1] "function" "kernel"  
> foo(99)
[1] 198
```

or maybe `c("kernel","function")`.  Or maybe just the class you want to add on, since functions seem to be quite happy without `function` in their class list:

```
> class(foo)=c("kernel")
> foo(2)
[1] 4
> is.function(foo)
[1] TRUE
>
```

However looking at the source for `kernlab` shows me these things are S4 classes. Check the source code for how the package creates these, since it uses a class hierarchy, where the various kernel functions have a specific class and inherit (via `contains`) the `kernel` class. Here's one example:

```
setClass("vanillakernel",prototype=structure(.Data=function(){},kpar=list()),contains=c("kernel"))

vanilladot <- function( )
{
  rval<- function(x, y = NULL)
    {
      if(!is(x,"vector")) stop("x must be a vector")
      if(!is(y,"vector")&&!is.null(y)) stop("y must be a vector")
      if (is(x,"vector") && is.null(y)){
        crossprod(x)
        }

      if (is(x,"vector") && is(y,"vector")){
        if (!length(x)==length(y))
            stop("number of dimension must be the same on both data points")
        crossprod(x,y)
          }

      }
  return(new("vanillakernel",.Data=rval,kpar=list()))
}
```

The base `kernel` class is defined in the packages' `aobjects.R` file this way:

```
setClass("kernel",representation("function",kpar="list"))
```